# Parse floats printed with %a in other languages

Tags: java, c++, scala

When you print a float or double in C++ using the `%a` format specifier in for example [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) you get an output in the style of `-0x1.d10e9a2c7a08p+10`. I need to read these floats in a scala application. So,

How do I reacquire a floating point number formatted in C++ via `%a` in Scala, Java or any language?

Comment: You parse `%a` formatted floating point numbers in arbitrary language using arbitrary methods

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the described standard is a [standard floating point literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) and can be parsed with both Java's `Double.parseDouble` and Scala's `String.toDouble`.